# Difference between "import lib.foo" and "import lib.foo as f" in Python

Tags: python, module, circular-dependency, python-import

I'm puzzled by how circular imports are handled in Python. I've tried to distill a minimal question and I don't think this exact variant was asked before. Basically, I'm seeing a difference between

```
import lib.foo
```

and

```
import lib.foo as f
```

when I have a circular dependency between `lib.foo` and `lib.bar`. I had expected that both would work the same: the (possibly half-initialized) module would be found in `sys.modules` and put into the local namespace. (From testing I noticed that `import lib.foo` really puts `lib` into the local namespace — okay, with that syntax I'll do `lib.foo.something` anyway.)

However, if `lib.foo` is already in `sys.modules`, then `import lib.foo as f` tries to access `foo` as an attribute on `lib` and raises AttributeError. Why does the behavior (seemingly) depend on the presence in `sys.modules`?

Also, where is this behavior documented? I don't feel that the [Python `import` statement reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) explains this behavior, or at least I couldn't extract it :-)

All in all I'm trying to change a code base to use the [oft recommended](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Imports#Imports) style where you import modules, not symbols in the modules:

```
from project.package import moduleA
from project.package import moduleB
```

But that fails when there are circular imports between the two modules. I had expected it to work as long as the top-level definitions in the two modules don't depend on each other (e.g., no subclass in `moduleB` with a base class in `moduleA`).

Test script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
rm -r lib; mkdir lib

touch lib/__init__.py

cat > lib/foo.py <<EOF
# lib.foo module
print '{ foo'
#import lib.bar # works
import lib.bar as b # also works
#from lib import bar # also works
print 'foo }'
EOF

cat > lib/bar.py <<EOF
# lib.bar module
print '{ bar'
#import lib.foo # works
import lib.foo as f # AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo'
#from lib import foo # ImportError: cannot import name foo
print 'bar }'
EOF

python -c 'import lib.foo'
```

Comment: Link http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Imports#Imports is broken - would be nice to readd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say `import lib.foo as f` what you are telling Python to do is the equivalent of `import lib.foo; f = lib.foo` at the bytecode level. You end up with an AttributeError in the issue being asked because `lib` in this case doesn't have `foo` set yet as an attribute. Python hasn't completed its import of `lib.foo` when it tries to do the assignment and thus has not set the attribute yet on `lib`; look at the Python 3.3 source for import where you can see where a [module is loaded](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ad51ed93377c/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#l1525) vs. couple statements farther down where a [module is set on its parent](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ad51ed93377c/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#l1529).

This is where you end up with some circular import issues. You need to let the import for `lib.foo` complete before you try to access `lib.foo`, else the attribute on `lib` simply won't exist yet for the bytecode to access. This might be why you think you are not using any top-level definitions directly in your code but in actuality you are through your import statements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So when I import `lib.foo`, `lib` is first imported and when `lib.foo` is imported, a `foo` attribute is set in `lib`. That is why `lib.foo.something` works later: it finds the `foo` *attribute* on the `lib` package — that also explains why `import lib.foo` puts `lib` into the local namespace.